# How take event.values[] not 0.0 from sensor Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION

Tags: android, geolocation, android-sensors

Where may be my fail and why Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION dont work correct?
It only return all 0.0
And all necessury permission i write in AndroidManifest.xml
It must work for android until android 4.0.3
I must know where  camera will be aimed. I know that SensorManager.getOrientation() work only for Android 4.0.3 and above, doesn't it?

```
Sensor mOrientation;
onCreate(...){
...
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
mOrientation = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
}
@Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mOrientation, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION){
        String mSensorString;
        mSensorString = "Azimuth: ";
        mSensorString += String.valueOf(event.values[0]);
        mSensorString += "\nPitch: ";
        mSensorString += String.valueOf(event.values[1]);
        mSensorString += "\nRoll: ";
        mSensorString += String.valueOf(event.values[2]);
        tv2.setText("\nOrientation: \n" + mSensorString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Nice that you have included your code and formatted it so well. But could you please include your question in the text or make it clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution, my smartphone hasn't magnetic sensor. I test this code on other device, all work well.